# How to decrypt string (encrypted in .NET) in Java client using apache.commons.codec Base64?

Tags: c#, java, .net, base64, apache-commons

I have a tricky situation here. I have a web service written in C# and it returns JSON stuff encrypted with the methods described below. This web service is consumed by a Java client, but I'm not able to get my string decrypted in client side, I've tried several Java examples of Java functions using DES algorithm but no luck since I always got this error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64

(My environment is Eclipse, jdk1.6.0_26, Android 2.1update emulator)

Please help!!

My C# functions are:

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="stringToEncrypt"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string Encrypt(string stringToEncrypt)
{
        try
        {
                const string key1 = "MY KEY HERE";

                byte[] iv = { Convert.ToByte("1"), Convert.ToByte("4"), Convert.ToByte("6"), Convert.ToByte("8"), Convert.ToByte("0"), Convert.ToByte("2"), Convert.ToByte("4"), Convert.ToByte("8") };

                byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key1);

                var des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
                byte[] inputByteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToEncrypt);
                var ms = new MemoryStream();
                var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, des.CreateEncryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                cs.Write(inputByteArray, 0, inputByteArray.Length);
                cs.FlushFinalBlock();
                return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
                Logger.Write(new ExceptionLogEntry(ex.ToString()));
        }

        return null;
}

/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="stringToDecrypt"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string Decrypt(string stringToDecrypt)
{
        try
        {
                const string key1 = "MY KEY HERE";

                byte[] iv = { Convert.ToByte("1"), Convert.ToByte("4"), Convert.ToByte("6"), Convert.ToByte("8"), Convert.ToByte("0"), Convert.ToByte("2"), Convert.ToByte("4"), Convert.ToByte("8") };

                byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key1);

                var des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
                byte[] inputByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(stringToDecrypt);
                var ms = new MemoryStream();
                var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, des.CreateDecryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                cs.Write(inputByteArray, 0, inputByteArray.Length);
                cs.FlushFinalBlock();
                var encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                return encoding.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
                Logger.Write(new ExceptionLogEntry(ex.ToString()));
                return "-1";
        }
}
```

My Java function using commons-codec-1.5.jar is:

```
KeySpec ks = new DESKeySpec("MY KEY HERE".getBytes("UTF-8"));
SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES").generateSecret(ks);
IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(Hex.decodeHex("1234567890ABCDEF".toCharArray()));
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);

byte[] decoded = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64("MY ENCRYPTED STRING HERE"));

Log.e(TAG, "DECODED->" + new String(decoded, "UTF-8"));
```

But I always got this error:

> **07-05 04:48:20.822: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1270): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64
```

shows that the problem isn't (necessarily) in your code at all - it can't find `Base64.decodeBase64`, so you're probably not deploying the Apache Commons Codec library properly. (Admittedly it's not *exactly* the error I'd have expected to see, but I'm more used to desktop Java than Android.)

However, you might as well use [Android's built-in Base64 class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html) instead of working out why you couldn't get Apache Commons Codec to work.

Comment: Hi Jon, actually I've tried with several versions of that apache library (I wasn't expected something from apache would crash), I'll try android's base64 class. Thanks!

Comment: @Jafet: It's not the method itself failing - it's the VM failing to even *find* the method.

Comment: I'm sharing my final solution for this problem, go to my blog: http://jafetsanchez.com/post/7562162652/rijndael-on-c-and-java